# PHP drop fields into array and update array results on another table not working?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Hi there :) probably my title will be a bit hard to understand, sorry i couldn't make it any more brief. Anyway, what I have done is I've created a script that will get column data from a table where the timestamp on the rows are more than 30 days old. Then, it will store these IDs on an array, and will then loop through the arrays on another table. Sadly, nothing happens and I don't seem to get an error when I run the script.

Here's what the script says:

```
<?php

// connects to the DB
include ('connectdb.php');

//query that gets the "trade_id" from the table with all the trades, where the "open_time" is older than 30 days, "close_price" is NULL.
$result = $db->query("SELECT trade_id FROM trades WHERE open_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS) AND close_price IS NULL");
// create an array
$rows = array();
// loop through the table and drop the data into the array
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $rows[] = $row;    
}       

$count = count($rows);
$i = 0;
//loops through the table
while($i < $count){
//updates the table "orders" where the unique_ID matches the trade_ID, and will change the column "notified" to -1
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE orders SET notified=? WHERE unique_id=$rows[$i]");
    $update->execute(array(-1));
//updates the table "trades" where the trade_ID matches the trade_ID, and will change the column "close_price" to -1
    $update2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE trades SET close_price=? WHERE trade_id=$rows[$i]");
    $update2->execute(array(-1));
    $i++;
}   
// Closes connection
$db = null;

?>
```

I've left notes throughout the code, however I am convinced I may have done the time script in the $result that may be wrong. Again, I am unsure why it doesn't update the rows. Any help I do vastly appreciate :)

Comment: `$row` is an array, not a string. so `$rows[$i]` is incorrect, also that should be parameterized as well. Try `$rows[] = $row['trade_id']`. I also would just `foreach` on `$rows` rather than the `while`...

Comment: ah right, so what should I do to make it work? Sorry im a bit of a noob at PHP :P EDIT: Thank you!

Comment: just tried it, and still it doesn't seem to update any rows. Maybe there is a second problem with the code?

Comment: ive just done some testing, where it prints the array values 1 by 1 and then creates a new line, they all display, but there is something wrong with the "Update" function, it doesnt work. Ive not yet parameterized it, how do I do that?

Comment: In your first update query, is the notification id supposed to be spelled 'notified' or 'notifeid' ?

Comment: Diddle dot - yes its meant to be "notified"

Comment: thanks for all your help, but this is my error, I am deeply sorry. Still you did help me fix and optimize some things, so thank you for that :)

Comment: Take a look at my answer, I think it may make your code a bit cleaner, and will close a potential SQL injection hole.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a rough answer of how I'd try it.

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT trade_id FROM trades WHERE open_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAYS) AND close_price IS NULL");
// create an array
$rows = array();
// loop through the table and drop the data into the array
$rows = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
foreach($rows as $row){
//updates the table "orders" where the unique_ID matches the trade_ID, and will change the column "notified" to -1
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE orders SET notified=? WHERE unique_id= ?");
    $update->execute(array(-1, $row['trade_id']));
//updates the table "trades" where the trade_ID matches the trade_ID, and will change the column "close_price" to -1
    $update2 = $db->prepare("UPDATE trades SET close_price=? WHERE trade_id=?");
    $update2->execute(array(-1, $row['trade_id']));
}   
// Closes connection
$db = null;
```

1. Use `fetchAll` so you get all the records at once, don't need that `while` and variable assignment.
2. Use `foreach` rather than a `while` then you don't need to make your own counter.
3. Parameterize the `update` queries; otherwise could be open to second order SQL injection..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this:

```
WHERE unique_id=$rows[$i]
```

to this:

```
WHERE unique_id={$rows[$i]}
```